# Does starting a new game erase which collectibles I've found?

Tags: titanfall-2

When I go to start a new game in Titanfall 2 the game states:

> Starting a new game resets all saved Campaign progress

Does this reset include forgetting which collectibles I've found during the campaign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware (a bit blurry memory because last time I've played TF2 is 2 to 3 years ago) yes, they will reset, and at least [reddit agreed to me](https://www.reddit.com/r/titanfall/comments/aqyir8/comment/egjffry/).

As that comment says, you can always start fresh without getting reset by just picking first mission via mission select (or whatever it's called, I've forgot its name, maybe chapter select?).